# separate a text into numbers and letters using php

Tags: php, text

using php
I'm having a problem , I wanna read a text and separate it in numbers and letters
for example I wanna read this text: 4FS+2d,14 and get this output:'4' 'FS' '+' '2' 'd' ',' '14'
any idea how to do that?
thanks

Comment: what about the `comma` ?

Comment: your right i forgot to write it. any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = '4FS+2d,14';
$arr = preg_split('#([\W]+|[\d]+)#i', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($arr);
exit;

// output
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => FS
    [2] => +
    [3] => 2
    [4] => d
    [5] => ,
    [6] => 14
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/preg_match_all).

```
$string = '4FS+2d,14';
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+|[^0-9a-zA-Z]+/', $string, $matches);
//               ^ digits
//                      ^ chars 
//                                ^ not digits, not chars
echo json_encode($matches); // json_encode for readability

//     [["4","FS","+","2","d",",","14"]]
```

---

```
[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+|[^0-9a-zA-Z]+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/5kFTPfCF5JbZtHHn)

Comment: @fk, picture for you :^ )

Comment: just one more thing how can i access the outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<?php
$str = "4FS+2d,14";
for($loop=0;$loop<strlen($str);$loop++) {
    $len[] = $str[$loop];
}
print_r($len);
?>
```

demo link: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/de8-4yp